# Can we have a form postback and use html controls for javascript validation of the controls?

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, validation

Can we have a form with method = "post" and use HTML controls and perform a javascript validation on the controls.

for ex:

```
<body>
<form method="post">
<div class="login">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Username" id="username">
  <input type="password" placeholder="Password" id="password">      
  <input type="submit" value="Sign In">
</div>
</form>
</body>
```

Can we have a form like the above one and do basic validations using JS and after successful login redirect to another page.

How do I redirect to another page after successful validation?

Comment: What do you need to validate?

Comment: A post sends things to a server page. It cannot be received by client based JavaScript. However validation can be done on the client. But the password will always be visible.

Comment: @Stefano basic textbox validation for empty values

Answer (score 0):

You can validate the data filled in the form both in Javascript and in the backend, and I suggest you to mandatory do it in the backend. If data are valid you can then continue your work flow like redirecting to another page. Also for redirecting you can do it or in backend or in frontend.